# Parsing periods in a column dataframe

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv with one of the columns that contains periods:

timespan (string): PnYnMnD, where P is a literal value that starts the expression, nY is the number of years followed by a literal Y, nM is the number of months followed by a literal M, nD is the number of days followed by a literal D, where any of these numbers and corresponding designators may be absent if they are equal to 0, and a minus sign may appear before the P to specify a negative duration.

I want to return a data frame that contains all the data in the csv with parsed timespan column.

So far I have a code that parses periods:

```
import re

timespan_regex = re.compile(r'P(?:(\d+)Y)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)D)?')
def parse_timespan(timespan):
    # check if the input is a valid timespan
    if not timespan or 'P' not in timespan:
        return None

    # check if timespan is negative and skip initial 'P' literal
    curr_idx = 0
    is_negative = timespan.startswith('-')
    if is_negative:
        curr_idx = 1

    # extract years, months and days with the regex
    match = timespan_regex.match(timespan[curr_idx:])

    years = int(match.group(1) or 0)
    months = int(match.group(2) or 0)
    days = int(match.group(3) or 0)

    timespan_days = years * 365 + months * 30 + days

    return timespan_days if not is_negative else -timespan_days



print(parse_timespan(''))
print(parse_timespan('P2Y11M20D'))
print(parse_timespan('-P2Y11M20D'))
print(parse_timespan('P2Y'))
print(parse_timespan('P0Y'))
print(parse_timespan('P2Y4M'))
print(parse_timespan('P16D'))

Output:
None
1080
-1080
730
0
850
16
```

How do I apply this code to the whole csv column while running the function processing csv?

```
def do_process_citation_data(f_path):
    global my_ocan

    my_ocan = pd.read_csv(f_path, names=['oci', 'citing', 'cited', 'creation', 'timespan', 'journal_sc', 'author_sc'],
                          parse_dates=['creation', 'timespan'])
    my_ocan = my_ocan.iloc[1:]  # to remove the first row
    my_ocan['creation'] = pd.to_datetime(my_ocan['creation'], format="%Y-%m-%d", yearfirst=True)
    my_ocan['timespan'] = parse_timespan(my_ocan['timespan']) #I tried like this, but sure it is not working :)

    return my_ocan
```

Thank you and have a lovely day :)

Answer (score 0):

Like with Python's builtin `map`, Pandas also has that method. You can check its documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). Since you already have your function ready which takes a single parameter and returns a value, you just need this:

```
my_ocan['timespan'] = my_ocan['timespan'].map(parse_timespan) #This will take each value in the column "timespan", pass it to your function 'parse_timespan', and update the specific row with the returned value
```

And here is a generic demo:

```
import pandas as pd

def demo_func(x):
    #Takes an int or string, prefixes with 'A' and returns a string.
    return "A" + str(x)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Column_1": [1, 2, 3, 4], "Column_2": [10, 9, 8, 7]})
print(df)
df['Column_1'] = df['Column_1'].map(demo_func)
print("After mapping:\n{}".format(df))
```

**Output:**

```
   Column_1  Column_2
0         1        10
1         2         9
2         3         8
3         4         7
After mapping:
  Column_1  Column_2
0       A1        10
1       A2         9
2       A3         8
3       A4         7
```